# Using prefix paths in GatsbyJS and hosting app on S3 yields 403 forbidden

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, gatsby

I'm trying to host a gatsby application on an S3 bucket that contains links to three pages. when I do a gatsby build passing the parameter --prefix-paths and serve it locally everything works without any issues. When moving same build to S3 I keep getting `403 Code: Access denied` on every page (at least my tab icon shows).

Now when I build the same application without specifying prefix paths and host it on S3, everything renders without any issues. Is there anyone that has been able to work around this issue?

What I'm expecting:

when I hit:

- someapp.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/portal/ to take you to the first page.
- someapp.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/portal/page2 to take you to the second page.
- some.app.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/portal/page3 to take you to the third.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Why do you need prefix paths when it renders without issues without them? Edit your question and supply the prefix code. That way it's easier to answer your question.

Comment: I'm trying to use AWS API Gateway as a proxy and  I would gave to set a prefix path in order to access my resources. I ended up finding an answer on my own. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with an answer after going through API Gateway docs for a while. What I ended up doing was structuring my methods and resources as such. Once set, all my resources were available.

[image]